# Sorting in lexicographic (alphabetical) order in java

Tags: java, sorting

I have a for-loop that prints the data. In the first position is a letter and in the second is number.
Like this:

```
H 8
T 3
A 9
F 4
```

How can I sort this data in lexicographic (alphabetical) (key is a letter) order? Output must be:

```
A 9
F 4
H 8
T 3
```

Should I put the data into the list and use `Collections.sort(list);`? In this case the numbers are not in the necessary position.

P.S Actually this is a small part of a homework, but I do not know how to solve this.

Comment: You should try searching before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/708698/590177

Answer (score 3):

If you define your data type as:

```
class Data implements Comparable<Data> {
     private char letter;
     private int number;

     public int compareTo(Data d) {
        if(letter > d.letter) return 1;
        if(letter < d.letter) return -1;
        return 0;
     }
}
```

Then you can put your `Data` instances in an `ArrayList` and use `Collections.sort`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an implementation of [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), for example a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), using the character as the `Key` and the number as the `Value`. That way you don't have to encapsulate the character and the number in one object and still keep the mapping.

[This answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java/922533#922533) shows how to get the keys from that map in a sorted order. From there, you can use the keys and get the values in a sorted order as well.

Answer (score 0):

*for java users

put your data into a hashmap(yourMap).

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
youMap.put(H,8);
youMap.put(T,3);
youMap.put(A,9);
youMap.put(F,4);



List sortedKeys=new ArrayList(yourMap.keySet());
Collections.sort(sortedKeys);

for(String key: sortedKeys){
system.out.println(key+" "+yourMap.get(key) );
```