# sorting arraylist object by two values

Tags: java, oop, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I have an arraylist of movies that holds the movie title and director. I need to create a comparator that will first sort the directors in alphabetical order, and will sor the movies made by each director in alphabetical order. I also want to sort this data in ascending OR descending order.

e.g.

1. James Cameron:
2. Steven Spielberg

Comment: So do it, what's the problem?

Comment: Can you show the struggle with your code?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @batsta13: you're supposed to do your part of the job. If you're just looking for a free solution without even trying anything, then hire and pay a competent programmer. Otherwise, show what you have tried, and click on the links that have been given to you and show how to solve your problem (because you also failed to find the many questions that ask for the exact same thing).

Comment: fuk u. Quit ur bitching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you've sorted the director list....
just take one director as an key value in outer loop and then start comparing each and every movie name in inner loop...

[How can I sort a List alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708698/how-to-sort-list-alphabetically)

this would be helpful...
do some searching next time....it is easy to find such solutions... :) ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708698/how-to-sort-list-alphabetically

Comment: check this link out....

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. And there should be 0 loop involved to sort a list of movies.