# Arrange a List<String[]> alphabetically

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I have a List object. I want to arrange the List of String[] alphabetically according to item at [0] in each string array. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, use a custom comparator. There are *lots* of questions on SO about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708698/how-to-sort-list-alphabetically