# Listing customers by name from a text file

Tags: java

I'm working on a project where I have customers with reservations on a text file. I'm looking to be able to "listCustomer" them then have them come up in alphabetical order by customer name. All I have right now is:

```
public static void listCustomers(List<Customer> customers) {  
    System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "Customers");
    System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "=========");
    for (Customer c : customers) {
        System.out.format("\033[33m%s\033[0m%n", "Customer"); 
        System.out.format("\033[33m%s\033[0m%n", "--------"); 
        System.out.println(c);
    }       
}
```

This works as it does list the customers, but it doesn't list them alphabetically as I'd like them too. I kinda new to coding so if this is a dumb way to do it let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)

Comment: I cannot comment, so please check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708698/how-can-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Collections.sort(Comparator<? super Customer>...)` method to achieve this.

You only need to implement the Comparator yourself.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class CustomerComparator implements Comparator<Customer> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
        return c1.toString().compareTo(c2.toString());
    }
}
```

This will compare the customer's toString() values lexicographically, or in other words, alphabetically, in ascending order. **If you need to sort by the customer's name, replace the toString() with the appropriate name property. (Usually getName())**. `Collections.sort` will sort using `toString()`, so you can simply enter `customers.sort()` if your toString() method returns the name property.

To print the results:

```
public static void listCustomers(List<Customer> customers) { 
    CustomerComparator comparator = new CustomerComparator();
    customers.sort(comparator);

    System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "Customers");
    System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "=========");
    for (Customer c : customers) {
        System.out.format("\033[33m%s\033[0m%n", "Customer"); 
        System.out.format("\033[33m%s\033[0m%n", "--------"); 
        System.out.println(c);
    }       
}
```

If you'd like to dispense with an additional class, you can declare the interface inline, like so:

```
customers.sort(new Comparator<Customer>() {
    public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
        return c1.toString().compareTo(c2.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: It says "an enclosing instance that contains CustomerComparator is required"  Sorry if this is obvious haha

Comment: The class `CustomerComparator` must be in its own file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(customers);
```

//then print with the same logic you have now

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with comparator like below.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

        customers.add(new Customer("001", "Namal"));
        customers.add(new Customer("002", "Lakmini"));
        customers.add(new Customer("003", "Ahas"));

        System.out.println("main().customers 1 : " + customers);

        Collections.sort(customers,new NameSorter());

        System.out.println("main().customers 2 : " + customers);

    }
```

}

**Customer.java**

```
public class Customer {

    public Customer(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.id + "|" + this.name;
    }

    private String name = null;
    private String id = null;

}
```

**NameSorter.java**

```
public class NameSorter implements Comparator<Customer>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }

}
```