# How do I display child of child's data from firebase in my RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I want to show data of all children inside all the Categories from the database (added the image below of what my database looks). I am adding data to my RecyclerView using the adapter which needs FirebaseRecyclerOptions object to be passed. I saw one answer where DataSnapshot was used to get child of child data, I tried to get the data using that and it showed me when I logged it in logcat (the commented code is what I tried using), but I do not know how to use that with my Adapter class.

This is what my database looks, I want the data inside of the highlighted fields:

```
{
    "Category_wise": {
        "education": {
            "udemy": {     <-Return data of this child
                "companyName": "Udemy",
                ...
            },
            "khanacademy": {     <-Return data of this child
                "companyName": "Khan Academy",
                ...
            }
        },
        "technology": {
            "google": {    <-Return data of this child
                "companyName": "Google",
                ...
            },
            "facebook": {    <-Return data of this child
                "companyName": "Facebook",
                ...
            },
        ....
    }   
}
```

In the below code, SCard is my Model Class and SCardAdapter is my Adapter Class.

This is my Fragment (HomeFragment) where I'm adding data into recyclerview:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Query query;
    private SCardAdapter<SCard, SCardAdapter.ViewHolder> adapter;

    public HomeFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.search_recyclerview);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        setQueryByOrder("technology", "totalInvestors");
        fetchResult(query);

        return v;
    }

//    protected void fetchAll(){
//        final DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Category_wise");
//        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
//                    Log.i(TAG, "4321: Name of each company: " + Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("companyName").getValue()).toString()
//                }
//            }
//            @Override
//            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
//        });
//    }

    protected void setQueryByOrder(String choice, String order){
        query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Category_wise").child(choice).orderByChild(order);
    }

    protected void fetchResult(Query query) {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<SCard> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<SCard>()
                        .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<SCard>() {
                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public SCard parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                return new SCard(
                                        Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("companyName").getValue()).toString()...);
                            }
                        })
                        .build();
        adapter = new SCardAdapter<>(options);
        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

This is my Adapter Class:

```
public class SCardAdapter<M extends SCard, V extends SCardAdapter.ViewHolder> extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SCard, V> {

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<SCard> options;
    public SCardAdapter(@Nullable FirebaseRecyclerOptions<SCard> options) {
        super(options);
        this.options = options;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(V holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position, SCard model) {
        holder.setName(model.getsName());
      ...
    }

    @Override
    public V onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.startup_search_card, parent, false);
        return (V) new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView simg2;
        TextView sname, sdesc, senddate, sperraised, snoin, sminam;
        ProgressBar sraisingprogbar;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            sname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sname);
          ...
        }

        public void setName(String string) {
            sname.setText(string);
        }
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you replace the schematic display of your database structure with the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Are you allowed to change the database schema?

Comment: Hey, Alex maybe you have a solution for a better database schema can I get your suggestion? I want to know your approach for this schema

Comment: Looks like you need to use your own adapter, not using firebaseui.

Comment: @AlexMamo yes sure

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine oh okay, I guess I might have to make a lot of changes in my adapter class then

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I want to display data inside of all the children of "Category_wise"s children into my recyclerview.

Comment: @AltajVirani No. Just simple not that hard. If you willing to change your adapter. I can share my answer then.

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine Yes mate sure, please share your answer.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the help, finally found the solution thanks to @TicherHaz FreePalestine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to create 2 loops since your json looks like that and store them inside an `arrayList`. You are suppose to get all the data there inside the arrayList.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category_wise").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            ArrayList<Scard> sCardList = new ArrayList<Scard>();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot shot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                        if (shot.exists()){
                            final Scard scard = shot.getValue(Scard.class);
                            if (scard != null){
                                sCardList.add(scard);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            final ScardAdapter scardAdapter = new ScardAdapter(sCardList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(scardAdapter);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Next you need to create your own adapter. You can search on Google also for more information. But you will get the point here.

```
public class ScardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScardViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Scard> sCardList;
    public ScardAdapter(final ArrayList<Scard> sCardList) {
        this.sCardList = sCardList;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ScardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.scard_item, parent, false);
        return new ScardViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ScardViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Scard model = sCardList.get(position);
        holder.getTvCompanyName.setText(model.getCompanyName);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sCardList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I tried your solution and it solved my problem.

Comment: @AltajVirani you are welcome. if you want to sort. can try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708698/how-can-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically