# Ordered list in HashMap Java

Tags: java

I am in need of a data structure, like:

```
Map<String, List<Profile>> profilePool;
```

What I need is the list to each key should be sorted. I can do it manually while doing `profilePool.put()` using some compare objecst on some attribute to keep the list ordered against the key. 
But can we have a compare function attached to the List<> so that whenever a object is inserted into the list, it should place it at a specific index, maintaining the order?

Or do we have any other data structure, easy to use and does the same task?

Comment: When you don't have duplicate elements, a `TreeSet` might work

Comment: [Why is there no sorted list in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-is-there-no-sortedlist-in-java)

Comment: @SilverNak Thanks. But unfortunately I can have duplicate elements.

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't provide it out of the box.
If it is worthy, you could create your own wrapper `SortedList` class that implements `List`.

At each time you add an element in it, you could identify the insertion position to use with a binary search and push the new value into this position.

Comment: "Java doesn't provide it out of the box" If this is the case then, I got my answer. I would have to either implement `List` or find out some other way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @GhostCat  You are right. It would not be as much as efficient to sort it  even if `Collection.sort()`  should be relatively fast as the List is already sorted.

Comment: Well, reality is again complicated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168891/is-it-faster-to-sort-a-list-after-inserting-items-or-adding-them-to-a-sorted-lis for example.

Comment: @Impossible, You are welcome. You could also use a `TreeSet` if the `Set` interface and constraints suit to your requirement.

Comment: plus one for suggesting to implement List using a wrapper instead of extending ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

If duplicate elements (based on `.equals()`) are fully interchangeable, you could use Guava's [SortedMultiset](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multiset). It only stores one instance of each duplicate element, and the iterator will return that same instance multiple times. That technicality aside, it can function the same as a SortedList.

```
Map<String, SortedMultiset<Profile>> profilePool;
```